# Calling and killing a parent function with onmouseover and onmouseout events

Tags: javascript, function, dom-events

I want to call the function upon the `onmouseover="ParentFunction();"` then kill it `onmouseout="killParent();"`.

Note: in my code the parent function is called `initiate();` and the killer function is called `reset();` which lies outside the parent function at the bottom of the script.

I don't know how to kill the `intitiate()` function my first guess was:

```
  var reset = function(){
  return initiate(); 
  };
```

here's my source code: any suggestions and help appreciated.

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

  <head>
  <title> function/event prototype </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styling.css" />

  </head>

  <body>

     <h2> <em>Fantastical place<br/>prototype</em> </h2>

    <div id="button-container">
         <div id="button-box">   
             <button id="activate" onmouseover="initiate()" onmouseout="reset();" width="50px" height="50px" title="Activate">  </button> 
         </div>  

         <div id="text-box"> 
         </div>
    </div>

    <div id="container">

        <canvas id="playground" width="200px" height="250px">
        </canvas>

        <canvas id="face" width="400px" height="200px">
        </canvas>

    <!-- <div id="clear"> </div> -->
    </div>


     <script> 
    alert("Welcome, there are x entries as of" +""+new Date().getHours());




 //global scope
  var i=0; 

var c1 = []; //c is short for collect
var c2 = [];
var c3 = [];
var c4 = [];
var c5 = [];
var c6 = [];

var initiate = function(){ //the button that triggers the program
  var timer = setInterval(function(){clock()},90); //copy this block for ref.


 function clock(){



  i+=1; 

   var a = Math.round(Math.random()*200); 
   var b = Math.round(Math.random()*250); 
   var c = Math.round(Math.random()*200); 
   var d = Math.round(Math.random()*250); 
   var e = Math.round(Math.random()*200); 
   var f = Math.round(Math.random()*250); 
   c1.push(a); 
   c2.push(b);
   c3.push(c);
   c4.push(d);
   c5.push(e);
   c6.push(f);

 // document.write(i);




    var c = document.getElementById("playground");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d"); 

   ctx.beginPath(); 
   ctx.moveTo(c3[i-2], c4[i-2]);
   ctx.bezierCurveTo(c1[i-2],c2[i-2],c5[i-2],c6[i-2],c3[i-1], c4[i-1]);
  // ctx.lineTo(c3[i-1], c4[i-1]); 

   if(a<200){
      ctx.strokeStyle="#FF33CC";   
   }
   else if(a<400){

     ctx.strokeStyle="#FF33aa";
   }
   else{
      ctx.strokeStyle="#FF3388";

   }



   ctx.stroke(); 

   document.getElementById("text-box").innerHTML=i+"<p>Thoughts.</p>"; 
  if(i===20){
    //alert("15 reached");
    clearInterval(timer);//to clearInterval must be using a global scoped variable.
   return; 
  }

 }; //end of clock











//setInterval(clock,150);
  var targetFace = document.getElementById("face");
  var face = targetFace.getContext("2d");


  var faceTimer = setInterval(function(){faceAnim()},80); //copy this block for ref. global scoped.

  function faceAnim(){

     face.beginPath(); 

  face.strokeStyle="#FF33CC";

  face.moveTo(100,104); //eye line
  face.bezierCurveTo(150,125,250,125,300,104);



  face.moveTo(200,1); //centre line
  face.lineTo(200,400);

  face.moveTo(125,111);//left eye lid
  face.bezierCurveTo(160,135,170,130,185,120);



  face.moveTo(150,116);//left eye 
  face.bezierCurveTo(155,125,165,125,170,118);

    face.moveTo(275,111);//right eye lid
face.bezierCurveTo(240,135,230,130,215,120);



  face.moveTo(250,116);//right eye 
  face.bezierCurveTo(245,125,235,125,230,118);

  face.moveTo(195, 118); //left nose
  face.lineTo(190, 160);
  face.lineTo(200,170);

  face.moveTo(190,160); //left nostroll
  face.lineTo(180,160);
  face.lineTo(191,154);

   face.moveTo(180,160); //left lower nostrol
  face.lineTo(200,170);

   face.moveTo(205, 118); //right nose
  face.lineTo(210, 160);
  face.lineTo(200,170);

  face.moveTo(210,160); //right nostroll
  face.lineTo(220,160);
  face.lineTo(209,154);

  face.moveTo(220,160); //right lower nostrol
  face.lineTo(200,170);



  face.moveTo(200,140); //outer triad
  face.lineTo(170, 100);
   face.lineTo(230, 100);
   face.lineTo(200, 140);

   face.moveTo(200,145); //outer triad drop shadow
  face.lineTo(170, 100);
   face.lineTo(230, 100);
   face.lineTo(200, 145);

    face.moveTo(200,130); //inner triad
  face.lineTo(180, 105);
   face.lineTo(220, 105);
   face.lineTo(200, 130);

  //face.lineWidth =0.6; 

        face.moveTo(280,111);//outer right eye lid
face.bezierCurveTo(240,140,230,135,210,120);

     face.moveTo(120,111);//outer left eye lid 
  face.bezierCurveTo(160,140,170,135,190,120);


    face.moveTo(162,174); //upper mouth line
  face.bezierCurveTo(170,180,230,180,238,174);

   face.moveTo(165,175); //mouth line bottom
  face.bezierCurveTo(190,Math.floor(Math.random()*25+180),210,Math.floor(Math.random()*25+180),235,175);


    face.moveTo(232,204); //head shape
    face.lineTo(340, 20);

        face.moveTo(168,204); //head shape
    face.lineTo(60, 20);

  face.stroke(); //exicute all co-ords.


  }; //end of face anim


    var clearFace = function(){

   document.getElementById('face').getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, 700, 750);

};

setInterval(clearFace,90); 


}; //end of parent function

    var reset = function(){

   document.getElementById('playground').getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, 700, 750);
  //clearInterval(faceTimer); 
   //delete initiate(); 
  }; 


    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please format your code for easier readability; also, I don't understand the question. What is the specific issue you're having?

Comment: in short i want to stop the initiate() function from running on the onmouseout event. how do i achieve this? i know the return keyword is 1 way of killing functions

Comment: `return` will get you out of a function while you are in that function's execution, but having other function `return initiate()` will do no such thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a variable in `reset()` e.g. `stop = true;`

Then check it in `faceTimer` or anyplace else...

Overall the structure should be this though,

```
///Globals
var queue = [], stop = false;
// drawing function ....
function draw(){
 if(stop || !Boolean(queue) || !Boolean(queue.length)) return;
 var current = undefined;
 while(Boolean(current = queue.pop()))
 {
    if(!stop){ 
     current(); 
     var nextTime = Number(current.nextInterval); 
     if(nextTime > 0) setTimeout(nextTime , draw || this); 
    }
    else if(Boolean(current.shouldBreak)) break;
 }
}
```

where `current` is a function which has been queued to do the drawing from faceTimer

e.g.

`var work = function(){ clock(); faceAnim(); queue.push(this); }; work.nextInterval = 500; work.shouldBreak = false; queue.push(work);`

Then initiate becomes `var initiate = work; initiate();`;

I have your example working @ http://jsfiddle.net/JtHQ4/18/

Comment: oki, gotta go to class now i'll tweak and report back in a few hours. niceone jay!

Comment: sorry, was away from a computer for 24 hours, gunna patch the code now.

Comment: heya jay appreciate the tips, i may re-code it when after the project is finished, but i'm still abit of a novice. by check it in 'facetimer()' , do you mean: 'var reset(){ var stop = true; }; var faceanim(){co ords.. if(stop===true){return; }};'

Comment: Essentially yes, why dont you upload something on jsFiddle and I will help you out?

Comment: alright jay, i'll do that! will link to a jsFid now

Comment: here's the jsFiddle as it runs in my text-editor. the script runs from within the body to get it working. here's the new fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/JtHQ4/8/)

Comment: i'm finding the code runs much smoother and correctly in the text editor, so if it's too laggy in fiddle, all the source code is there for you to run in an editor if you chose too. hover over the square button to start the program, the idea then is when hovering back out of the square to reset and kill the animation.

Comment: ok cool, i've declared the stop; var at the start of the script and use it in an if statement just below the faceTimer/setInterval var. the function at the bottom of the script reset() assigns a true value to the stop var onmouseout event. it does work in the sense that it's being recognised but return; isn't the right keyword to put in there i'm guessing. i was thinking clearInterval(faceTimer);

Comment: i should be, but when i use mouseout and the clearInterval(faceTimer) is activated it doesn't kill the animation for the face, i think it's to do with scoping of my functions and parent function maybe, where i have things nested. i'll keep twiddling.